# Excel removes my VBA project from .bin file

Tags: python, excel, vba

I want to add VBA project to my excel file I'm creating using 'xlsxwriter' library. In their example https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html they extract vba project from another excel file and add it to the current. I want to add an already existing .bin file to my excel file. The problem is that excel removes this file. Here is my python code

```
from xlsxwriter import *
import os

workbook = Workbook('ShipBattle.xlsm')
menuws = workbook.add_worksheet('Menu')
gamews = workbook.add_worksheet('Game')

workbook.set_vba_name('MyWorkbook')
menuws.set_vba_name('Sheet1')
gamews.set_vba_name('Sheet2')

workbook.add_vba_project('vbaProject.bin')
gamews.insert_button('F10', {'macro' : 'Test', 'caption' : 'End Turn', 'width' : 80, 'height' : 30})
workbook.close()
```

and here is my vba code from .bin file

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox "Hello, world!"
End Sub
```

Here is the window:
[pic of removing my vbaProject.bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxFoW.png)

Comment: In the docs, it shows `workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')` there is ./  also worksheet.insert_button('B3', {'macro': 'ThisWorkbook.say_hello'})  Thisworkbook may be needed.  I've not used it, reading out of interest, so apologies if no help.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I tried it with full path and adding "ThisWorkbook. ...", but it didn't work. I think, it is not the problem

Comment: Can you try [this example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_macros.html) from the docs using the vbaProject.bin file from the examples folder in the XlsxWriter repo. If it works (and it should) then try your vbaProject.bin. If there is still an issue then you can open a bug report on Github. You will need to add the vbaProject.bin if you submit a bug report.

Comment: @jmcnamara where can i find the .bin file's code?

Comment: @jmcnamara okay, I just copypasted all the code and typed this in my .bin file: `Sub Test()
MsgBox "Hello from Python!"
End Sub` and it still doesn't work. I'll try to post it on github or send an email to author of the library.

Comment: The vbaProject file from the example is [here](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/main/examples/vbaProject.bin?raw=true). And I am the author of the library. ;-)

Comment: @jmcnamara wow, with this .bin file it actually worked! my problem was that i thought that i can just type in some vba code. Now, i know that i have to firstly write it in excel and then extract from it. The only problem is that extracting doesn't work for some reason. I tried it with "$" symbol, from cmd and even using .bat file, but nothing worked. How can i extract it?

Comment: Changing the file extension to zip file allow you to extract will do this i think.